# angularJS ng-app value issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The following code works.

```
<body ng-app="" ng-init="names=['a','b']">
    <ul ng-repeat="x in names">
        <li >
             {{ x }}
        </li>
    </ul> 
</body>
```

but as soon I add a value to ng-app (say ng-app="myApp"), it stops working. Anyone would know why?

Comment: whats in your app.js? do you have a module called myApp setup there?

Comment: @iandayman: Okay, I think I am getting closer to the answer with your reply. I was assuming that the value used here is what I'd like to name my app. Are you suggesting that this name is simply calling the custom object I make in JS?

Comment: What you're doing by calling the ng-app directive is auto-bootstrapping an AngularJS module to the element on the page. So that element becomes the root of where your Angular app is. I'd highly recommend reading over the documentation for ngApp here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp -- and the documentation for angular.module here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: @NickP exactly that. As a side note I would suggest to use your browser's debugging tools. It will highlight these types of errors to you.

Comment: Thanks @iandayman & Sinan Bolel, This makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, you told angular by specifying name, that in this page all objects definitions and details which I am going to use is defined in a module called my app. Angular Search for it and does not find.

when you specify the ng-app you should specify the app definition, controller you can initialize these values from ng-init.

```
<html>
<body>
<div ng-app="myapp" controller="MyController">
      <span>{{personname}}</span>
</div>

<script>
// this will setup the myapp
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('MyController',function(){
$scope.personname='tammi';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a separate "app.js" (don't forget to reference it inside script tags in the html(view)) file and create an angular module and assign it to the global variable "myApp":

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

Then create a controller that will expose the data to the view via the $scope service:

```
myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.names = ['a', 'b'];
}
```

In the view, do the following:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="x in names">
        <li >
             {{ x }}
        </li>
    </ul> 
</body>
```